# Spring Boot Rest API with AJAX

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and Ajax for Web-UI. This is my UIController for adding and editing user.

```
@GetMapping("/user-form")
public String getUserForm(){
    return "userform";
}

@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", userRepository.findOne(id));
    return "userform";
}
```

I have project with Javascript checking whenever userform loads, is there any model attribute attached. If yes, how can I assign value to controls.

Comment: are you having any error when you're trying to hit your controller form your Ajax.
Also, I  could see that you haven't put **@ResponseBody** annotation on your controller.

Comment: @Sumit I have no error access controllers. But I wonder how can I get ${user.name} inside javascript.

Comment: Use- **th:inline** and put your scripting code in it like this <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript"> // your code here </script>

Answer (score 0):

Since you have assigned it to model now all you need to do is to show on view. for that you need to use it like:

```
<label value="${user.name}"/>
```

This is how you can use it on the view.

Comment: Hi Jayesh, I can show value in jsp. I wonder how could I access to user object in javascript.

Comment: Well for that you need to create rest services which you can call from Ajax and then assign the value returned to a variable in Javascript.